# "An error occurred while attempting to initialize a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object."

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net, connection-string

I started to write project on asp.net and faced with trouble. When I try to execute this code:

```
System.Web.Security.Roles.CreateRole("User");
```

I get an exception:
An error occurred while attempting to initialize a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection` object. The value that was provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an invalid syntax.
Parameter name: `connectionString`

That's part of the configuration of my project:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
      ...
      <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleProvider">
        <providers>
          <clear/>
          <add name="SqlRoleProvider"
               connectionString="ForumDB"
               applicationName="/"
               type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
        </providers>
      </roleManager>
    </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="ForumDB"
         connectionString="Data Source=(local)\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=ForumDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I initially thought that the connection string has been written wrong, but I checked several times. Also this code works:

```
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ForumDB"];
    DbProviderFactory providerFactory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(connectionString.ProviderName);
    DbConnection connection = providerFactory.CreateConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString.ConnectionString;
    connection.Open();
```

I am sure that the connection string has been written correctly. What is wrong?

Comment: Is this code being run on the same machine that houses the SQL Server instance?

Comment: @Shark, yes. Database is on the same machine on which the code runs.

Comment: Plz check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlroleprovider.aspx. It might be the `<clear/>` statement you have. But not sure. Also if possible post your complete `config`

Comment: @AmarPalsapure, this instruction is necessary to remove the same announcement of provider which has been on a previous run.

Comment: @Kovpaev: Is your `<connectionStrings>` section defined under the `<configuration>` node, or along with `<roleManager>` under `<system.web>`?

Comment: @tobias, <connectionStrings> defined in <configuration> section.

Comment: I made a mistake here: `connectionString="ForumDB"`. I had to write: `connectionStringName="ForumDB"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake here:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear/>
            <add name="SqlRoleProvider"
                connectionString="ForumDB"
                applicationName="/"
                type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"/>
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

I had to write:

```
connectionStringName="ForumDB"
```